# Can I use my green (mouse) USB-to-PS/2 adapter for keyboards?

Tags: usb, adapter, ps2

I have a USB keyboard which I want to connect over PS/2 to my computer.
I only have a green USB-to-PS/2 adapter which has the symbol of a mouse on it.

Can I use it for the USB keyboard anyways?

My motherboard has a PS/2-combo-socket, e.g. it accepts one mouse or one keyboard at once.

Comment: Be aware that this adapter will only work with PS/2-aware devices. It contains no logic whatsoever.

Comment: @DanielB How can I check if my USB keyboard is PS/2 compatible? Until now I thought every USB keyboard is converted well through this adapter. I only have normal keys and some media keys, and the keyboard has background illumination. I would only require the normal keys in the worst case.

Comment: They say the use of the adaption from usb back to PS2 can be dependant on the input device itself having hardware that can do that. The adapter is the same, but from what they tell me it will only work with devices that provided that compatability.

Comment: @Psycogeek I see, it looks like I have to check it out, I will post my results. It's a Logitech Illuminated Keyboard.

Comment: It sadly doesn't work for my keyboard, even the backlight doesn't turn on :/ Made sure the port is enabled in UEFI and all, but no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PS/2 Plug's themselves are made to be different colours as each colour send different signal's, and so they are not interchangable.

However, the converter in question may not follow these rules at all, and i would even go as far as to be surprised if it wouldnt work with both mice and keyboard.

So my best bet? just try it, there is no real easy way to determine if it will work without looking at the standard documentation that came with the converter.

Comment: And of course I have no documentation about the adapter, since it's one of those the people throw after you because they have too much of them =)

Comment: Aah typical, if anybody has any more light to shine on this, please do comment away!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The PS/2 plug is designed for both mice and keyboards.  This shouldn't be an issue so long as your OS can load the drivers for it but this would be true using USB anyways.

Comment: How can do you know exactly its made for both?

Answer (score 0):

There are different plugs in green and purple nor working the same way.
Nowdays some makers of plugs claim it's the same inner conections but I am not sure of that. I got a Purple one with my keyboard and that one works fine with both windows 10 and linux. A green one I have bought recently don't.

In windows you might have to change a value in the registry for a PS/2 keyboard to work. It seems like windows don't have this on "automagic" for some reason.

Also some keyboards work better connected as ps/2 (can handle more simultainious kaypresses)